# Git diff gives inconsistent results

Tags: git, diff

I get different results for the diff of some file in a subfolder (lets call it "subfolder/myfile.txt") when I do `git diff master` vs `git diff master -- subfolder/myfile.txt`. The former command does not include all the changes made to the file while the latter does. I should also note that I am calling these commands from a different branch than master. I have tried running different commands to see what works and doesn't work.

These commands show all the changes in the file:

```
git diff master -- subfolder/myfile.txt
git diff master -- subfolder
```

These commands don't show all the changes in the file:

```
git diff master
git diff master -- .
git diff master HEAD
git diff HEAD master
```

I have tried making further changes to the file, these changes do not get picked up by the non-working commands, but they do get picked up by the working commands. Additionally I have tried deleting and rebuilding the git index or cloning the git repo, neither action made a difference.

I attempted making a minimum working example but I could not reproduce the problem in a fresh new repo. I suspect that what has happened here is that the basic diff command has some caching in it that has gotten messed up.

Comment: That's definitely quite odd, because the `-- <path>` syntax runs the main diff machinery and just limits its output. The output-limiting does send the internal code through special optimized code paths, so you may have discovered a bug. A reproducer would be valuable.

Comment: Gotcha, that would make sense. Unfortunately I can't reproduce in a clean git repo, but the error is reproducible by cloning the original git repo. I don't want to share the repo publicly but am happy to share it with individuals for the purposes of investigating this bug.